# How can I get session id in php and show it?

Tags: php, session

I need to use some unique id like session id. ***How can I get session id in php?***

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` will get you all the values in session

Comment: Do you just need a unique ID or do you want to create a session?

Comment: i wonder who gets pleasure from closing topics - see this a lot these days.
this was 1st hit via google, and the 1st answer is the exact one i'm looking for.

Comment: `session_start();  echo session_id();`

Comment: @jcansell I think the issue here is that the first sentence asks for something different than the bold question (the likely reason Google brought us here). There are much more efficient ways to get a unique ID than with sessions, as detailed in other answers below.

Comment: looks the same to me, i can see that the OP's 1st language isn't UK English, but that shouldn't be an issue to normal humans.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
session_start();    
echo session_id();
```

Answer (score 21):

I would not recommend you to start session just to get some unique id. Instead, use such things as [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid) because it's intended to return unique id.

However, if you already have session, then, of course, use [`session_id()`](http://php.net/session_id) to get your session id - but do not rely on that, because "unique id" isn't same as "session id" in common sense: for example, multiple tabs in most browsers will use same process, thus, use same session identifier in result - and, therefore, different connections will have same id. It's your decision about desired behavior, I've mentioned this just to show the difference between session id and unique id.

Comment: unique_id isn't crytographically secure - reading around, it doesn't look like session_id isn't either.  rapid calls to unique_id will return the same id because it uses the time. as Hassan says, you may wish to add a prefix / suffix to your id to increase its uniqueness.

Comment: Security though obscurity isn't a good idea; in modern version of PHP something like random_bytes() could work if it needs to be crytpographically sound

Answer (score 10):

Before getting a session id you need to start a session and that is done by using:
session_start() function.

Now that you have started a session you can get a session id by using:
session_id().

```
/* A small piece of code for setting, displaying and destroying session in PHP */

<?php
session_start();
$r=session_id();

/* SOME PIECE OF CODE TO AUTHENTICATE THE USER, MOSTLY SQL QUERY... */

/* now registering a session for an authenticated user */
$_SESSION['username']=$username;

/* now displaying the session id..... */
echo "the session id id: ".$r;
echo " and the session has been registered for: ".$_SESSION['username'];


/* now destroying the session id */

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $_SESSION=array();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    echo "session destroyed...";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have uniqid function for unique id

You can add prefix to make it more unique

Source : http://pk1.php.net/uniqid

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {  
 if(!empty($_POST['login_username']) && !empty($_POST['login_password']))
    {
     $uname = $_POST['login_username'];
     $pass = $_POST['login_password'];
     $res="SELECT count(*),uname,role FROM users WHERE uname='$uname' and  password='$pass' ";
$query=mysql_query($res)or die (mysql_error());  

list($result,$uname,$role) = mysql_fetch_row($query);   
$_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
$_SESSION['role'] = $role;
 if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['role']=="admin")
 {
 if($result>0)
      {
       header ('Location:Dashboard.php');
      }
      else
      {
         header ('Location:loginform.php');
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -7):

In the PHP file first you need to register the session

```
 <? session_start();
     $_SESSION['id'] = $userData['user_id'];?>
```

And in each page of your php application you can retrive the session id

```
 <? session_start()
    id =  $_SESSION['id'];
   ?>
```

Comment: That's not what normally is referred to as "session ID".

Comment: i see wat u did dere... -1 -_-

Comment: Where is this sudden constant "id"? You missed the $ identifier on your variable (aka new readers).