# Check if php session string is valid and exists

Tags: php

Basically I want something like

```
$string = "dadeadad";

if(session_id($string)){
      // $string is a valid php session, not expired
}else{
      // $string is not a valid php session
}
```

But all I found is examples related to checking if a session was started (that is not what I want). Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: sessions variables are not magic, you compare the same way you compare any 2 vars `if($x==$y)`

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the session is set and equal to something.

I.e.:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['string'] = "dadeadad";

if(isset($_SESSION['string']) && $_SESSION['string'] == "dadeadad"){

   // session is true and equals to string
}

else{

   // do something here
}
```

Either way, you will still need to use a conditional statement to check if the session id equals something.

As outlined above and from Dagon `if($x==$y)`.

---

Example pulled from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302920/

Assign a variable to `session_id()` where you can later check if it equals to "something".

```
<?php
session_start();
$r=session_id();

/* SOME PIECE OF CODE TO AUTHENTICATE THE USER, MOSTLY SQL QUERY... */

/* now registering a session for an authenticated user */
$_SESSION['username']=$username;

/* now displaying the session id..... */
echo "the session id id: ".$r;
echo " and the session has been registered for: ".$_SESSION['username'];


/* now destroying the session id */

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $_SESSION=array();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    echo "session destroyed...";
}
```

Another example, taken from the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

```
<?php
$a = session_id();
if(empty($a)) session_start();
echo "SID: ".SID."<br>session_id(): ".session_id()."<br>COOKIE: ".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
```

Comment: could it be not set and still match ?

Comment: @Dagon doubt it. with `OR` sure

Comment: @Fred-ii- the "$string" is literally the session id. There should be an easier  to check if "session id X" is running or not, simply that...

Comment: @Fane [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) produces a string such as `0bdac8b0a85873b1657e4dc046e1cf61` so either way, you will need to use a conditional statement as already outlined to check if that string equals to `==` it (same principle). Dagon also left an example in comments. So I'd take a look at the manual on this http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php and it has a few examples. I can be of further help later, because I have to go somewhere for about an hour. I'd be glad to help you when I get back.

Comment: @Fane `if(session_id($string) && $string =="dadeadad" )` may work; untested. But again... `session_id()` produces a longer string than `dadeadad` by default, so you will need to test what I already mentioned.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the thing is I want to ask the server if the session string "$something" is running so I can later set it via session_id($something). If I do session_id() == "$something" I should assume a session had already been started right?

Comment: @Fane Hi Fane. You can check using `if (session_id() === ""){...} else{...}` this checks if it equals nothing. Or the reverse `if (session_id() !== "")` this checks if `session_id()` is empty or not, or `if(!empty($string))` or `if(isset($string))`. I made an edit to my answer (earlier) from another one I found that may be of help also. You will need to reload it to see it. That's about the best I can do/think of right now. Try those out and if you have a hard time, let me know.

Comment: @Fane there's another answer given, see if that helps also.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Your are looking for something like this:

```
session_start();

$sessId = 'voi44bhncdt58j5gfssnje37n11';

if(session_id() === $sessId){
    echo "valid php session";
} else{
    echo "invalid php session";
}
```