# How to destroy session from another browser logged in

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, codeigniter-3

I want to start session based on database data in CodeIgniter. Something like if I logged into my application using Chrome browser at the same moment I logged into Firefox with the same id and password. Now, is it possible to destroy my Chrome browser session from Firefox logged in?

I found same functionality on facebook, that shows all active sessions and we can destroy it from another device/browser login/session.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: on login, create a session id and save it to a database. when  you login in another browser, first check in  database to see if the user has any active session if yes, flag the user or update the session or logout the user.

Comment: My session stroed in local machine how can I set it based on database? Because, my session is only destroy when I am logged out from my application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302733/how-can-i-get-session-id-in-php-and-show-it that will help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a token in order count logged user from various devices or browsers. So you can display all active sessions to user or remove previous sessions.
The important key of this solution is using mentioned token per each request then you can check valid request by its token.
Store device IMI or something like that per each session

Comment: Yes, I have created access token, device and browser info with version but the issue is once I logged into my account the session data stored in local machine when I clicked logout from application than and than session will destroy, how can I destory session when I changed logged in status 1 to 0 in database?

Comment: @SahilBuddhadev in log out process you have to remove its token from database then each request with that token will not works

Comment: Ok I'll try to code with access token and get back to you if I'm getting any error. Thank You @Hamid